# Calculate mean, median, and mode in Rust

Tags: statistics, rust

I'm learning Rust using [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/second-edition/). I'm trying the assignment at the end of [chapter 8 — Hash Maps](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch08-03-hash-maps.html#summary).

The task is:

> Given a list of integers, use a vector and return the mean (average), median (when sorted, the value in the middle position), and mode (the value that occurs most often; a hash map will be helpful here) of the list.

The average value and the median were very easy for me, but I struggle solving the last part of the task. I do have a working solution (see below), but I'm sure there must be some more elegant and readable way (using the standard library?) for this.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
fn main() {
  let  mut numbers = vec![42, 1, 36, 34, 76, 378, 43, 1, 43, 54, 2, 3, 43];

  let avg: f32;
  let median: i32;
  let mode: i32;

  { // calculate average
      let mut sum: i32 = 0;
      for x in &numbers {
          sum = sum + x;
      }

      avg = sum as f32 / numbers.len() as f32;
  }

  { // calculate median
      numbers.sort();
      let mid = numbers.len() / 2;

      median = numbers[mid];
  }

  { // calculate mode
      // new HashMap
      let mut times = HashMap::new();

      // count
      for x in &numbers {
          let cnt = times.entry(*x as usize).or_insert(0);
          *cnt += 1;
      }

      let mut best: (i32, i32) = (*times.iter().nth(0).expect("Fatal.").0 as i32, *times.iter().nth(0).expect("Fatal.").1 as i32);

      for x in times.iter() {
          if *x.1 > best.1 {
              best = (*x.0 as i32, *x.1);
          }
      }
      mode = best.0;
  }

  println!("AVERAGE: {}", avg);
  println!("MEDIAN: {}", median);
  println!("MODE: {}", mode)

}
```

Comment: You can use iterator's `sum` method to get the sum, and `max_by_key` to find the highest value in the HashMap.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

1. Learn to love [rustfmt](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rustfmt). For example, the Rust standard is 4-space indents.
2. Learn to love [Clippy](https://github.com/Manishearth/rust-clippy), which can show you the more idiomatic way to iterate over a collection:

   ```
   warning: it is more idiomatic to loop over references to containers instead of using explicit iteration methods
     --> src/main.rs:43:18
      |
   43 |         for x in times.iter() {
      |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^ help: to write this more concisely, try: `&times`
      |
      = note: #[warn(explicit_iter_loop)] on by default
      = help: for further information visit https://github.com/Manishearth/rust-clippy/wiki#explicit_iter_loop
   ```
3. There's no reason to declare your variables early in the function. That's the kind of thing you would do in very old C or JavaScript and isn't required in modern languages. Declare them as late as possible.
4. Extract methods for each of the operations you'd like to perform. This allows you to remove the artificial blocks inside the main function and makes the comments into code identifiers. This removes the need for the variables in the main function at all.
5. There's no need to use a `Vec` as you never add or remove items from the list. A plain array will suffice.
6. As mentioned in the comments, `Iterator::sum` already exists. If it didn't, you could use something like `Iterator::fold`.
7. Your implementation of `median` is incorrect. When there are an even number of values, the median is defined as the average of the two middle values. I've not changed your code for this because doing so would require changing the type of `median` and I'm not sure how you'd prefer to do so.
8. There's no need to cast the value to `usize` when counting the number of occurrences; storing the `i32` in the `HashMap` makes more sense.
9. You can dereference the number using `&value` in the for loop binding.
10. Once you have built your mapping of occurrences, you can iterate over it, taking the maximum value with `Iterator::max_by_key`, throw away the count using `Iterator::map`, then have a single `expect` call.
11. Use a better error message than "Fatal" - describe *what* the problem was.
12. Don't use `nth(0)` - that's just `.next()`

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn average(numbers: &[i32]) -> f32 {
    numbers.iter().sum::<i32>() as f32 / numbers.len() as f32
}

fn median(numbers: &mut [i32]) -> i32 {
    numbers.sort();
    let mid = numbers.len() / 2;
    numbers[mid]
}

fn mode(numbers: &[i32]) -> i32 {
    let mut occurrences = HashMap::new();

    for &value in numbers {
        *occurrences.entry(value).or_insert(0) += 1;
    }

    occurrences
        .into_iter()
        .max_by_key(|&(_, count)| count)
        .map(|(val, _)| val)
        .expect("Cannot compute the mode of zero numbers")
}

fn main() {
    let mut numbers = [42, 1, 36, 34, 76, 378, 43, 1, 43, 54, 2, 3, 43];

    println!("AVERAGE: {}", average(&numbers));
    println!("MEDIAN: {}", median(&mut numbers));
    println!("MODE: {}", mode(&numbers));
}
```

A clever one-pass solution for `mode` is also possible:

```
fn mode(numbers: &[i32]) -> Option<i32> {
    let mut counts = HashMap::new();

    numbers.iter().copied().max_by_key(|&n| {
        let count = counts.entry(n).or_insert(0);
        *count += 1;
        *count
    })
}
```

Comment: Well, thank you for your excellent answer which is actually I bit more than I asked for in the first place, but it helped a lot, indeed. My problem was that I did not unterstand the '.map_by_key'-function, because I'm just started learning Rust and this usage of the function's parameters is completly new to me.

Comment: @PEAR *which is actually I bit more than I asked* — yup, that's one of the reasons I recommended that this question be moved from Stack Overflow.

Comment: This answer is really instructive. However, the goal of this assignment is to work with `Vec`, not plain array type. I have deduced this based on the fact, that it is under Common Collections section in the Book.

Comment: @AlBundy See [Why is it discouraged to accept a reference to a String (&String), Vec (&Vec), or Box (&Box) as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/155423). TL;DR, the functions should all take `&[T]` / `&mut [T]`, but you can then use them with either an array or `Vec` (`numbers = vec![42, ...`).

Comment: Super answer, but I have one little doubt yet: why `sum()` needs `i32` and the compiler cant get that from the array type?

Comment: @elect does [Why can't Rust infer the resulting type of Iterator::sum?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41017140/155423) answer your question?

Comment: Your median implementation has n*log(n) complexity, but median can be computed in linear time. Unfortunately Rust doesn't have this built in. There are, of course, crates the provide it.

[QuickSelect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) is a sibling to QuickSort. It's n^2 worst case. But similar to QuickSort there are a variety of improvements. 

C++ provides this out of the box via [std::nth_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element).

Comment: [`nth_element`, you say?](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.select_nth_unstable)

Comment: Implementation for `median` is wrong. When the number of elements is even you have to return the average of the two elements in the center, the return type should be `f32`.

Answer (score 0):

That is an incorrect method to calculate median. The array length may odd or even.

When the array length is even, we need to take the mean of the two middle elements:

```
fn median(array: &Vec<i32>)->f64{
        if (array.len() % 2)==0 {
            let ind_left = array.len()/2-1; 
            let ind_right = array.len()/2 ;
            (array[ind_left]+array[ind_right]) as f64 / 2.0

        } else {
                array[(array.len()/2)] as f64
        }
}
```

Comment: Is that addition liable to overflow?  We probably want to convert to float before adding.